# How to retrieve the protocol used by an Apache camel endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel, protocols, endpoint

I wish to develop a generic java bean that will be included in all my camel routes (for personalized logging purposes). The route will call my java function in a processor and pass it the exchange object (and other stuff if needed).

How can I detect the type of the first endpoint that the route listens to ? it can be from ftp, http, jms etc ... and the relevant informations I would like to log are in different headers according to the endpoint protocol, for instance "CamelFileName" for ftp.

I have a workaround testing if the "CamelFilename" header exists then I know the endpoint listens to ftp server, or I could parse the endpointURI, but is there a more reliable/seeded function to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the from route on the Exchange, using the `getFromEndpoint` and `getFromRouteId`.

See the Exchange javadoc: http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.2/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html

Comment: Thanks Claus. As I said I can retrieve the Endpoint but can't then find which of its properties will give me the protocol.
getFromRouteId also returns a String with URI, do you mean I need to search for substrings into it ? No more precise property or function to get this info ?

Comment: From endpoint you can get the url, and there you can find out the protocol

Comment: But this is exactly what I was talking about in my first message. I can do that but I'm willing if there is a more reliable way to do it, with a true function of property